# How to add references using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, il

I am writing a compiler for a language that runs on the .NET framework. I'm trying to generate code for an import statement. Basically

```
import System.Drawing
```

Should behave like

```
using System.Drawing;
```

in C#. The import statement will also support things like:

```
import Foo.Bar in "foo.dll"
```

Which will import the Foo.Bar class in foo.dll. My question is how would I go about linking these into my generated program using Reflection.Emit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just: consume the library. Meaning, you just use types / methods from foo.dll in your emitted code. The `Reflection.Emit` wrapper will add the necessary reference metadata automatically. Note that this means that if your code imports a library and then doesn't use it, then that reference will not exist in the generated IL. Which funnily enough is **exactly** what the C# compiler does too (and probably the VB one).

Comment: Okay so I need to use reflection on foo.dll to grab the methods and classes and simply use them in the emitted il? Also that's interesting that C# does that, so unused references don't import anything then?

Comment: @mirhagk yes, exactly that

Comment: @mirhagk as an additional, you might find it worthwhile to look at IKVM.Reflection.dll; that has the same API, but some slightly better abilities, for example the ability to load assemblies in a totally isolated way, that even allows for generating dlls for different frameworks - for example, generating a dll for WinRT, Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, etc - all from a .NET 2 (or higher) exe.

Comment: 2 questions about the IKVM.Reflection.dll. First of all, is it stable/tested (looks pretty decent), and second of all, you say it generates for multiple platforms, does it also run on those platforms? (web and phone would be really cool)

Comment: @mirhagk yes it is stable etc, although I did find a couple of glitches, they were fixed in under a day. You can use the generated assemblies on those platforms, but IKVM.Reflection itself is a full .net (2.0 iirc) assembly. You can't use it to bypass the meta-programming restrictions on iOS, if that was your plan.